# What do the shift parameters of iMA() function mean?

Tags: mql4

Can somebody explain me what is the difference between both **`shift`** parameters of the `iMA` function on an example?
 According to the `MQL4` documentation:

> **`ma_shift`**  - Moving Average shift. Indicators line offset relate to the chart by timeframe.
>
> **`shift`**     - Index of the value taken from the indicator buffer
>                   ( shift relative to the current bar the given amount of periods ago )

Which parameters are taken by the standard MA indicator?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
double iMA(string symbol, int timeframe, int period, int ma_shift, int ma_method, int applied_price, int shift)
```

For the packaged standard Indicator 'Moving Average', the 'Shift' field amends the 'ma_shift' parameter.

[image: Indicator]

For the packaged Custom Indicator 'Moving Averages', the 'MA_Shift' field amends the 'ma_shift' parameter.

[image: Custom Indicator]

Nothing in either indicator allows you to amend the last 'shift' parameter.

[image: comparison]

---

Graphically, for the standard Indicator 'Moving Average', changing the 'Shift' field shifts the MA line right (with a +ve number) and left (with a -ve number) by the number of periods as defined by the integer value.

ma_shift = 0:
[image: default]

ma_shift = 4:
[image: ma_shift +4]

ma_shift = -4:
[image: ma_shift -4]

Code-wise, when polling iMA() and setting ma_shift to 4, e.g.

```
double iMA("EURUSD", PERIOD_H1, 8, 4, MODE_SMA, PRICE_CLOSE, 0)
```

you will get the moving average value 4 periods back.

---

This is a simple textual indicator showing the iMA() value, with the period, ma_shift, and shift parameters editable. Play with it and verify against the 'Moving Average' indicator(bring up Data Window):

```
#property indicator_chart_window

extern int period   = 8;
extern int ma_shift = 0;
extern int shift    = 0;

void start(){
   string A1=StringConcatenate("Stat: ", DoubleToStr(MA(),5));
   Comment(A1);
   return (0);
}

double MA(){
   return(iMA(NULL, 0, period, ma_shift, 0, 0, shift));
}
```

---

The last 'shift' parameter in the iMA() function shifts the periods used for calculation, and can only be a +ve number. A -ve number will request future non-existent periods. You can try putting a -ve number in the text indicator above to see what you get. (0.00000) As mentioned above, the indicators do not allow editing this parameter, simply because they are effectively the same.

```
double iMA("EURUSD", PERIOD_H1, 8, 4, MODE_SMA, PRICE_CLOSE, 0)
```

same as

```
double iMA("EURUSD", PERIOD_H1, 8, 0, MODE_SMA, PRICE_CLOSE, 4)
```

So why is it there? Most likely as a standardisation with other indicators, e.g. http://docs.mql4.com/indicators/iAlligator
where the 'shift' parameter is an overarching determiner for which periods to calculate from, and the separate jaw_shift, teeth_shift, lips_shift being independent parameters to graphically shift the lines drawn.

Answer (score 3):

The "**`ma_shift`**" is a graphical shift of "the line" displayed. This is only relevant to displaying the array values. Not much relevant to coding <kbd>**`EA`**</kbd>s.
The "**`shift`**" is a value of element, taken into calculation. By default, the value of the shift is zero (the zero bar (the last bar)). Any shifts in bars in **`MQL4`** are **from the last bar backwards.**

**Example**:
You compare two `SMA`. One is 20 periods/0 shift, the other is 10 periods/4 shift. Every comparison between the `SMA`s will be done between the 20 period `SMA` on the last bar in the array and the 10 period `SMA` 4 periods back in the array.
**In numbers...** 
Lets say the 20 `SMA` in the last bar is `1.1000`.
Lets say the 10 `SMA` is as follows:
`1.1050` on 0 bar (last bar)
`1.1000` on 1 bar (previous bar)
`1.0950` on 2 bar (two bars back)
`1.0900` on 3 bar (three bars back)

**Result:**
Is `20SMA( shift0 ) > 10SMA( shift0 )` => NO
Is `20SMA( shift0 ) > 10SMA( shift3 )` => Yes

In summary. the `MA_shift` is a shift of the line forward/backward. The `shift` is a barvalue shift backwards (from the 0/last bar).

Meaning, a 4 shift represents the `MA` value 4 bars back. This option is available in coding only, for the purpose of algorithm construction. The `ma_shift` is irrelevant to `EA`s, because when the computer calculates `MA` crosses it uses the array values, not the line itself.

Best of luck!